Azure Isolated HttpTrigger Max Request body size 30000000 bytes limit
Experiencing an issue when uploading any file greater than 30meg with "Request body too large. The max request body size is 30000000 bytes".
This is an Isolated Azure Function running the aspnetcore integration.
The function throws the exception when performing the copyasync
using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); await req.Body.CopyToAsync(ms); byte[] webmBytes = ms.ToArray();
Within the function start I am just calling the ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication. Can this be extended to solve the issue within the host?
I have tried specifying the FUNCTIONS_REQUEST_BODY_SIZE_LIMIT within the environment variables, adding [RequestSizeLimit(40000000)] to the function method. But am still hitting the aspnet core default 30meg ish limit, rather than the Azure Function limit of 100meg.

Try:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;

namespace Acme.AzureFunctions
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IHost host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
                .ConfigureServices(svc =>
                {
                    svc.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(opt =>
                    {
                        opt.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
                    });
                    ...



Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Ok, here are some additional details.
I had the same problem as described in this issue. I searched the Internet for the solution, and compiled the suggestions I found (some of them on Stack Overflow which I consider a very valuable resource) into something that worked for me. And here it is.
For background and syntax, see Microsoft documentation.
Can't find it? Me neither. Configuration has been a "black box", convention-based, changing with each new version of each individual Nuget package I have to reference.
Browsing the source code of that stuff is something I don't care to do.
